# chrome notification doesn't display and return error

Tags: javascript, workbox

I got a problem with API notification with Chrome. It did not manage to display the notification and return an error into the console. I did not experience this problem with Firefox.

#### index.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {  

    Notification.requestPermission(function (status) {
        console.log('notification permission status: ', status);
        displayNotification();
    });

    function displayNotification() {
        if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
            navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
                .then(function (reg) {
                    var options = {
                        body: 'Buzz! Buzz!',
                        icon: '/static/img/logo_menu.png',
                        vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
                        tag: 'vibration-sample'
                    };
                    reg.showNotification('Hello world !', options);
                })
        }
    }

}, false);
```

#### Error message

```
notification permission status:  granted index.js:25
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'showNotification' of undefined at index.js:25
```

Someone know why I experience this problem only on Chrome ?

#### Edit :

I didn't mention but I have a script tag :

```
<script>
        // Check that service workers are registered
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            // Use the window load event to keep the page load performant
            window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
            });
        }
    </script>
```

that root to `sw.js` file :

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.4.1/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  console.log(`Yay! Workbox is loaded `);
} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}
```

I solve the problem in addition to index.js `setTimeout()`. By this way, I'm waiting for that service worker working to start to read my file.

Comment: Have you [registered a service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register)? BTW if you are running in the main client script you can just show a [notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification) (with permission) without dealing with service workers.